# How can i collect the data i want from 4 pages of a website with for loop for url in urls?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, web-scraping, url

im a newbie in python, actually trying to pull off an assignment for a uni course, and im tryin to do multiple pages scraping with python pandas. Im trying to exact all the data from the table that is in each page in this site https://aaiasb.gr/publications/investigation-reports

after i managed to scrape all the urls i tried this, but i only get the data from the first page:

```
#imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import time

import pandas as pd


pd.set_option('display.max_rows', None)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', None)
response=requests.get('https://aaiasb.gr/publications/investigation-reports', ) 
response

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
soup 

base_url = 'https://aaiasb.gr/publications/investigation-reports'
ending = '?start='
numbers = [50, 100, 150]

urls = [base_url]
for n in numbers:
url = base_url+ending+str(n)
urls.append(url)

df = pd.DataFrame(urls) 
df = df.rename(columns={df.columns[0]:'url'})
df

for url in urls:



response = requests.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
soup_doc = BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')



 entries = []

 page=soup.select('div.cck_page_items')[0]

 rows = page.find('table').find_all('tr')[1:] 
   

    conclusion_date1 = tr.find_all('td')[0].find_all('div')[1].text.strip()


    conclusion_date2 = tr.find_all('td')[0].find_all('div')[2].text.strip()


    incident_info = tr.find_all('td')[1].find_all('div')[0].text.strip()

    incident_type = tr.find_all('td')[1].find_all('div')[1].text.strip()

    incident_description = str(tr.find_all('td')[1].find_all('span', attrs={'uk-icon':'info'})[0])
    fatalities = tr.find_all('td')[1].find_all('div')[2].text.strip()

    fatalities_description = str(tr.find_all('td')[1].find_all('span', attrs={'uk-icon':'info'})[1])

    area = tr.find_all('td')[2].find_all('div')[0].text.strip()

    registry = tr.find_all('td')[2].find_all('div')[1].text.strip()
    
    aircraft_type = tr.find_all('td')[2].find_all('div')[-2].text.strip()

    aircraft_info = tr.find_all('td')[2].find_all('div')[-1].text.strip()


    area_info = tr.find_all('td')[2].text.strip()


    dict = {'conclusion_date1': conclusion_date1,
        'conclusion_date2': conclusion_date2,
        'incident_info': incident_info,
        'incident_type': incident_type,
        'incident_description': incident_description,
        'fatalities': fatalities,
        'fatalities_description': fatalities_description,
        'area': area,
        'registry': registry,
        'aircraft_type': aircraft_type,
        'aircraft_info': aircraft_info,
        'area_info': area_info}

    entries.append(dict)
     
df1 =pd.DataFrame(entries)
```

Comment: you should not be using the word "dict" as a variable name. Also where is the list of urls you are using ? This code does not show how you are navigating to the next page ?

Comment: You have indentation issues in your code. Also after fixing these indentation issues, your code does not run. Please provide a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: @ScottC okay, i added the whole code. I think that my main problem is that i don't know exactly how to navigate to the next pages as you noticed

Answer (score 0):

The main issue has to do with your indentation and location of assignments, e.g. `entries = []` and `df = pd.DataFrame(entries)` need to be in the right places. Try the below.

```
# imports
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import unicodedata
import pandas as pd


pd.set_option("display.max_rows", None)
pd.set_option("display.max_columns", None)

base_url = "https://aaiasb.gr/publications/investigation-reports"
suffix = "?start="
start_indices = [0, 50, 100, 150]

urls = [base_url + suffix + str(index) for index in start_indices]
entries = []

for url in urls:
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")

    table = soup.select("div.cck_page_items").pop().find("table")

    for row in table.find_all("tr")[1:]:
        cols = row.find_all("td")

        conclusion_date1 = cols[0].find_all("div")[1].text.strip()
        try:
            conclusion_date2 = cols[0].find_all("div")[2].text.strip()
        except IndexError:
            conclusion_date2 = "N/A"

        incident_info = cols[1].find_all("div")[0].text.strip()
        incident_type = cols[1].find_all("div")[1].text.strip()
        fatalities =    cols[1].find_all("div")[2].text.strip()

        info_hovers = cols[1].find_all("span", attrs={"uk-icon": "info"})
        incident_description =   ' '.join(unicodedata.normalize("NFC",info_hovers[0]['uk-tooltip']).split())
        fatalities_description = ' '.join(unicodedata.normalize("NFC",info_hovers[1]['uk-tooltip']).split()).replace("<br>","\n")

        area =      cols[2].find_all("div")[0].text.strip()
        area_info = '\n'.join(list(cols[2].strings)[-3:]).strip()

        registry = cols[2].find_all("div")[1].text.strip()
        aircraft_type = cols[2].find_all("div")[-2].text.strip()
        aircraft_info = cols[2].find_all("div")[-1].text.strip()

        entry = {
            "conclusion_date1": conclusion_date1,
            "conclusion_date2": conclusion_date2,
            "incident_info": incident_info,
            "incident_type": incident_type,
            "incident_description": incident_description,
            "fatalities": fatalities,
            "fatalities_description": fatalities_description,
            "area": area,
            "registry": registry,
            "aircraft_type": aircraft_type,
            "aircraft_info": aircraft_info,
            "area_info": area_info,
        }

        entries.append(entry)

df = pd.DataFrame(entries)

print(df.head())
print(df.tail())
```